# Sending bash commands to an open terminal buffer in emacs

Tags: bash, emacs, ansi-term

I've been trying to improve my emacs life lately, and one thing I've done is make use of `projectile` and `perspective` to organize my buffers sensibly.

As part of this I wrote an elisp function to open up (or return to) a named ansi-term buffer that is project-specific. This allows me to quickly drop into a bash terminal for the project I'm currently looking at.

What I have been having trouble finding out after plumbing the interwebs is whether or not it is possible to send bash commands to an open ansi-term buffer from within emacs. Specifically, I'm trying to make sure the ansi-term buffer cds to the correct project root directory when it's first opened. This requires grabbing context from the `projectile` package first, so it's not something I can plop into my `.bashrc`.

Ideally I would be able to write an elisp function that:

1) selects an ansi-term buffer by name (since I can have one open with a unique name for every project)

2) sends and executes a command in that buffer

Is there any way to do this?

***EDIT***

Final solution for anyone who is interested:

```
(defun visit-project-term-buffer ()
  "Create or visit a terminal buffer."
  (interactive)
  (if (not (get-buffer (persp-ansi-buffer-name)))
  (progn
    (split-window-sensibly (selected-window))
    (other-window 1)
    (ansi-term (getenv "SHELL"))
    (rename-buffer (persp-ansi-buffer-name))
    (end-of-buffer)
    (insert (format "cd %s" (projectile-project-root)))
    (term-send-input))
(switch-to-buffer-other-window (persp-ansi-buffer-name))))
```

Comment: Sounds cool, will give that a try. Did you look into `shell-pop` and `shell-here` ? http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Shell#shell-pop they don't fully answer your question because shell-pop will use one single shell window when you want many for different projects (and me too!), but their code might help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this work for you? It switches to a buffer named `*terminal*` and runs `echo hello`:

```
(defun my-echo ()
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer "*terminal*")
  (end-of-buffer)
  (insert "echo hello")
  (term-send-input))
```